# How to create a certain number of threads based on a value a variable contains?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a integer variable, that contains the number of threads to execute. Lets call it `myThreadVar`. I want to execute `myThreadVar` threads, and cannot think of any way to do it, without a ton of `if` statements. Is there any way I can create `myThreadVar` threads, no matter what `myThreadVar` is?

I was thinking:
`for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i) { std::thread t_i(myFunc); }`, but that obviously won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to execute some number of threads. What do you want to do with them? Do you want to tell if they're done? Do you expect to get a value back?

Comment: @NicolBolas I just want them to execute a generic function. I do not care about return values, or when they are done, as long as they finish before the program finishes.

Comment: Then you need the main function to `join` the threads. Add another for loop for thread joining and that will wait until all the threads are done before leaving the for loop. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

Comment: @TonyRuth I do know what `join` is, as I've used threads before. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @FlareCat I guess I do not understand the question then. What is wrong with using thread joining? What will it not accomplish that you want to accomplish?

Comment: @TonyRuth I need to spawn a certain amount of threads, that can all be spawned without using `std::thread t_1(myFunc); std::thread t_2(myFunc); std::thread t_3(myFunc); ... std::thread t_i(myFunc); ... t_1.join(); t_2.join(); t_3.join(); ... t_i.join();`, and can be accessed from a `for` loop, that can spawn a thread based on the iterator's value (`i`). (In which `i` is a changing variable)

Comment: You seem to be missing the concepts of arrays, best used via `std::vector`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array or vector of threads, put the threads in, and then if you want to wait for them to finish have a second loop go over your collection and join them all:

```
std::vector<std::thread> myThreads;
myThreads.reserve(myThreadVar);
for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i)
{
    myThreads.push_back(std::thread(myFunc));
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this is what I wanted. Didn't know I could spawn a thread with `std::thread(myFunc)`, thought I had to have an object name. Thanks!

Comment: Any object constructor produces an rvalue which can be put into an object, passed to a function, used as an array entry, etc. It's like calling func(25); vs int num = 25; func(num);

Comment: Ohh, got it. Helpful hint. Thanks again!

Comment: @NicolBolas I think so. Is the empty thread constructor smart enough to not do anything? Hopefully. If not, this could be fixed by using vector::reserve instead, as pointed out by Lingxi.

Comment: @NicolBolas according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread, the empty thread constructor does not actually start a thread, so I don't see a big problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas I misunderstood the vector(size_t) constructor. Good point. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

While other answers use `vector::push_back()`, I prefer `vector::emplace_back()`. Possibly more efficient. Also use `vector::reserve()`. See it live [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gKakIFUyeUga1GBx).

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void func() {}

int main() {
  int num = 3;
  std::vector<std::thread> vec;
  vec.reserve(num);
  for (auto i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    vec.emplace_back(func);
  }
  for (auto& t : vec) t.join();
}
```

Comment: A reasonable point. Instead of reserve, you can simply pass num into the vector constructor.

Comment: @Straw1239 That's not good. Doing so defeats the whole purpose of using `emplace_back()`. It constructs empty `std::thread` objects within the vector. `reserve()` does not call any `std::thread` constructor. It just allocates the necessary memory.

Comment: @FlareCat I'm tired of typing. More typing means more typos. So, if you can use `auto`, why not? :-)

Comment: @Lingxi Thanks, I didn't know reserve just allocated memory without constructing the threads. However, I would guess the overhead of empty thread objects is small.

Comment: @Lingxi because int has three letters while auto has four?

Comment: Just adding: using `int` as type works, but semantically more meaningful would be `std::size_t`. The second loop could be shortened to `for (auto & t : vec) { t.join(); }`

Comment: @DanielJour Nice catch. Updated :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, obvious the best solution is not to wait previous thread to done. You need to run all of them in parallel.
In this case you can use `vector` class to store all of instances and after that make `join` to all of them.
Take a look at my example.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void myFunc() {
    /* Some code */
}

int main()
{
    int myThreadVar = 50;
    std::vector <thread> threadsToJoin;
    threadsToJoin.resize(myThreadVar);
    for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i) {
        threadsToJoin[i] = std::thread(myFunc);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsToJoin.size(); i++) {
        threadsToJoin[i].join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean std::thread? Additionally, a slightly nit-picky point is that the vector will dynamically expand to size, an unnecessary inefficiency when you know the required size in advance.

Comment: @Straw1239 You are right, thanks. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void myFunc(int n) {
  std::cout << "myFunc " << n << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int myThreadVar = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i) { 
  std::cout << "Launching " << i << std::endl;
  std::thread t_i(myFunc,i); 
  t_i.detach();

  }
}
```

> g++ -std=c++11 -o 35106568 35106568.cpp
>
> ./35106568

```
Launching 0
myFunc 0
Launching 1
myFunc 1
Launching 2
myFunc 2
Launching 3
myFunc 3
Launching 4
myFunc 4
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is doing what OP wants: You're waiting for each thread to finish before starting the next. As such, you're running the `myFunc` serial, thus could get rid of the threads.

Comment: @DanielJour Yep, that is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Oops, I used join() instead of detach().  fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the thread so you can send it to join.

```
std::thread t[myThreadVar];
for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i) { t[i] = std::thread(myFunc); }//Start all threads

for (int i = 0; i < myThreadVar; ++i) {t[i].join;}//Wait for all threads to finish
```

I think this is valid syntax, but I'm more used to c so I am unsure if I initialized the array correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately in C++ this isn't standard if myThreadVar is a variable.

Comment: It's also still not valid syntax: `t[i] = std::thread(myFunc)` would work, but two other answers already show how this is done in C++.

Comment: @Straw1239 In this example, `myThreadVar` would need to be a `const int`, which it is not. Also, you are missing a `:` in line 2, with std::thread.